# How do I define in which format `datetime` values are shown when a DataFrame is displayed on the Python console?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe, datetime-format

I have a pandas DataFrame `df` with a few `datetime` columns. In the Python console a sample of the frame is displayed like this:

```
>>> df

         action             dt_completed              dt_created             dt_modified 
39       update  2010-11-07 22:04:48.668 2010-06-07 07:23:40.536 2017-07-17 06:12:48.059 
6056    release  2010-03-25 10:44:42.575 2010-03-24 17:21:54.751 2017-07-17          NaN 
5913    publish  2018-12-15 11:12:13.000 2018-12-14 00:30:58.393 2018-12-15 11:12:17.441 
7589     create  2011-09-03 22:55:23.656 2011-08-11 12:48:23.543 2011-09-03 22:55:23.656
```

When I explore the DataFrame I'm only interested in seeing the *date* portion of the `datetime` value. How can I tell pandas to display a DataFrame *on the console* only with the date portions of `datetime` values?

I looking for something like [display.precision](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/options.html#available-options), but for `datetimes` not for `floats`. Or some way to (globally?) overwrite pandas' datetime-to-string conversion function.

---

**Please note:** I'm not after *changing* the values in the `datetime` columns to dates or after adding new columns with shortened fields, but rather I'm looking to alter the *display* of the `datetime` columns in the console only.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this....

Lets create some date.... (Sorry I am too lazy)

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
data={'1':[datetime.now(),datetime.now()],
      '2':[datetime.now(),datetime.now()],
      '3':[datetime.now(),datetime.now()]}

df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data,orient='index')
df.columns=['date1','date2']
```

I can see the data ....

```
df.head()
```

Something like

```
    date1   date2
1   2019-03-26 12:28:51.080622  2019-03-26 12:28:51.080627
2   2019-03-26 12:28:51.080628  2019-03-26 12:28:51.080628
3   2019-03-26 12:28:51.080629  2019-03-26 12:28:51.080630
```

I use a custom style

```
def mydateformat(date):
    return "{}-{}-{}".format(date.year, date.month, date.day)

df2=df.style.format({'date1':mydateformat})
df2
```

Which shows

```
    date1       date2
1   2019-3-26   2019-03-26 12:41:02.834557
2   2019-3-26   2019-03-26 12:41:02.834558
3   2019-3-26   2019-03-26 12:41:02.834560
```

To check it has not altered the date1 column

```
df['diff']=-1
df['diff']=df.date1-df.date2
```

And to view again ....

```
df2
```

I see - which is the new Column in df with style in df2.

```
    date1   date2
1   2019-3-26   2019-03-26 12:42:14.417441  -1 days +23:59:59.999995
2   2019-3-26   2019-03-26 12:42:14.417443  -1 days +23:59:59.999999
3   2019-3-26   2019-03-26 12:42:14.417444  -1 days +23:59:59.999999
```

The slight rounding caused by the timestamp accuracy.... not the roungind on the date1 column.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Very Interesting! Not exactly what I was hoping for, but pretty close if it works. Will check it out.

Comment: Mmmh, doesn't seem to work: After customising `df` with the `df.style...` declaration,  displaying `df` still shows the full format for `date1`. And why do you issue `df.style...` a second time below creating the diff column?

Comment: @halloleo

Try.... 
    df2=df.style.format({'date1':mydateformat})

That seems to hold the value - you can modify df.... and still keep the reformatted data in df2

Comment: When I use exactly your example typing `df2` on the command line outputs "`<pandas.io.formats.style.Styler object at 0x7fca8965a0b8>`". `df2` is not a DataFrame, but a Styler object. I'm using Python 3.6.4 and pandas 0.24.2.

Comment: @halloleo Yes df2 is a html view of the data. So no .head() or Column mainipulations. More info at https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html

Comment: Thanks for the linkl! However, in a normal Python console `df2` returns only the string represenation of the style object, not a (text) list of the DataFrame content. `df2.render()` gives me the raw HTML, which in the Python console isn't very readable either.  Do you use some special console on top of Python like Jupyter/IPython?

Comment: @Halloleo until looking at your question I had never seen the .style method at all in Pandas. I do all my Pandas work in Jupiter Lab - Except when it goes to production, when it is usually encased in a Flask Rest-Api.

Comment: I use s normal Python console. - That explains the difference. :-)

Answer (score -1):

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

data={'1':[datetime.now(),datetime.now()],
  '2':[datetime.now(),datetime.now()],
  '3':[datetime.now(),datetime.now()]}

df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data,orient='index')
df.columns=['date1','date2']
df['date3'] = df['date1'].apply(datetime.date)
df['date4'] = df['date2'].apply(datetime.date)
df
```

Comment: This solution does *not* list the existing datetime columns in the way I am asking for. It just ads new columns.

Comment: Here, date1, date2 are the existing columns and the date3, date4 are the new columns which are holding the values without time details. It is not having your data to work with, but you can try it with your data as well.